# Using react-typical with react version 18 , animation not smooth

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animations

I want to implement react-typical so firstly I installed it using --force because its saying that your react version is incompatible and I don't want to downgrade my react. So when I'm using it, the animation is not that smooth.
What can I do!!
I tried using react-type-animation also, it says that TypeAnimation not found in react-type-animation.
Please help!!

```
<h1>
  {" "}
  <Typical
    loop={Infinity}
    steps={[
      "Enthusiastic Dev ",
      1000,
      "Full Stack Devloper ‍",
      1000,
      "MERN Stack  Dev ",
      1000,
      "Java Enthusiast ",
      1000,
      "React Developer ",
      1000,
    ]}
  />
</h1>
```